# Cannot access google cloud VM via SSH client through browser after VM restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created GCP VM for one month and connect VM instance through GCP console via browser.It worked fine for past one month until VM restart. I did not create ssh key/edit metadata and very thing so far is used default setting. I cannot establish connection after VM restart. The browser kept prompt me cannot establish the connection. I can ping this VM from another VM through VPC. any advise on it. Thank in advance.

Comment: Any advise/comments on it. I cannot access at all....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to connect a Linux instance via the SSH. You can connect to an instance via the [terminal](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools). You can connect via the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) Web UI which is in general the most convenient way to connect to an instance. Also, you can use [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) and run below command to connect to an instance via SSH:

> $ gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE_NAME]

You can also use [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) to connect your instance from the Cloud Console web UI by using the same command as above. You can connect via the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) using the Google Cloud Platform Console, the gcloud command-line tool, or a third-party SSH client.

The serial console authenticates users with SSH keys. Specifically, you must add your public SSH key to the project or instance metadata, and store your private key on the local machine from which you want to connect. There are other [advanced methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced) to connect to an instance which you can find at this link.

By default, the gcloud compute command-line tool uses the $USER variable to add users to the /etc/passwd file for connecting to virtual machine instances using SSH. You can [specify a different user](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips#sshusers) using the --ssh-key-file PRIVATE_KEY_FILE flag when running the gcloud compute ssh command. Depending on your use case and convenience, you can use any method consistently.

If you fail to connect to your instance upon following these methods then I would suggest to check this [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) page for SSH and follow the instruction that matches your use case.